# Find all tiles by ID in layer

Tags: tilemap, phaser, tiles

In phaser 2.6.2, is there a way to retrieve all tiles given their ID from a `TilemapLayer`? The method [searchTileIndex](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Tilemap.html#searchTileIndex) on `Tilemap` works well to retrieve a tile. It has a `skip` parameter that allows to loop through the tiles, so I've come with the following code:

```
var walls = [];
var skip = 0;
do {
    var tile = map.searchTileIndex(Tiles.ID_WALL, skip, false, wallLayer);
    if (tile !== null) {
        walls.push(tile);
        skip++;
    }
} while (tile !== null);
```

but it looks very cumbersome to say the least. Am I missing a simpler method, kind of `getAllTiles(id)` or something?